# How can I use training in a project for selecting objects in images?

Tags: training-data, toloka

Training is a pool of free tasks that performers can complete as practice. Training tasks include correct responses and hints. I created some tasks related to multiple-choice but now I have an issue for using training for selecting objects in images. Is it possible to create?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a training pool here, because in order for the assignment to be accepted by the system as correct, the object selected by the user must exactly match the control object. This is almost impossible. To select performers, create a regular pool with non-automatic acceptance. Review assignments manually and assign a skill based on the percentage of accepted responses. To only allow skilled performers to label the main pool, set a filter by skill in the pool to "my skill" >= 70. https://yandex.com/support/toloka-requester/concepts/reviewing-assignments.html